# Can't npm install serialport (or 'node-gyp rebuild') offline

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, node-gyp, node-serialport

I try to install the package `serialport` (that is dependency of `oxygen-cli`) in our internal network **without access to the internet** during the `npm install -g serialport` he tries to rebuild `node-gyp`.

I got an error and I solved it, and another error etc. Now I stuck with this error:

```
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  serialport.cpp
  serialport_win.cpp
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
C:\Users\yehoshaa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serialport\node_modules\nan\nan.h(24): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'node_version.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\s
rc\serialport_win.cpp) [C:\Users\yehoshaa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serialport\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\build\bindings.vcxproj]
C:\Users\yehoshaa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serialport\node_modules\nan\nan.h(24): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'node_version.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\s
rc\serialport.cpp) [C:\Users\yehoshaa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serialport\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\build\bindings.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\yehoshaa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\serialport\node_modules\@serialport\bindings
```

[image]

When I try to run only `node-gyp rebuild` I got this error:

> LINK: fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\myuser\AppDate\Roaming\npm\Release\node.lib' [C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\build\binding.vcxproj]

[image]

I checked the `binding.vcxproj` file and I see this line:

```
<AdditionalDependencies>C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\$(Configuration)\node.lib</AdditionalDependencies>
```

I tried to search the `node.lib` in my machine but I didn't find it.

If I remove this line from the file and run `node-gyp build` it works, but because I must to do `rebuild` the file downloaded again with the problematic line.

### I succeeded to install the package if I add the flag `--ignore-scripts` but it's ignore all the scripts from all the dependencies, is it ok?

Do you know how to solve it? or how to install `sertialport` **without** to do `node-gyp rebuild` (to ignore only this script but not all the dependencies scripts)?

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago I've solved problem with node-gyp build but I don't remember how.

Here is what I use right now:

https://github.com/tBlabs/BluePill.Daemon/tree/master/add_to_node_modules